# Linq ignoring spaces in OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

I am running a query to retrieve a list of suburbs. When I apply an OrderBy (I want the ordered alphabetically)

```
query.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
```

I am given the following order:

```
MOUNT ADA
MOUNTAIN BAY
MOUNTAIN GATE
MOUNTAIN VIEW
MOUNT ALFRED
MOUNT BEAUTY
```

It appears that the spaces are ignored and ordering by the suburb name without spaces.
What do I need to do to order by correctly? I think they should be in the following order:

```
MOUNT ADA
MOUNT ALFRED
MOUNT BEAUTY
MOUNTAIN BAY
MOUNTAIN GATE
MOUNTAIN VIEW
```

Comment: What are you running your query against?  A database, a collection of objects, something else?  If it's a database, it's determined by how that column is *`collated`* in the database.  If you do a standard `SELECT` and an `ORDER BY` on that column, you should get the same response (because that is what your query is telling the database to do).  What exactly are you querying?

Comment: `.OrderBy(m => m.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` orders like that. But a standard string order should also do the same.

Comment: I tried a few different engines (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL) with default collations and got the expected order. I couldn't think of any collations to try. You really do need to specify *which* engine and collation you're using.

Comment: The quesry is against the database. Yes, it is the collation

Comment: We are using PostgreSQL with an en_US.UTF-8 collation.
I would still like to be able to sort in the order I excpect.

Comment: and you are sure, it's spaces in the database, not some other type of whitespace ?

Comment: Yes, definitey spaces

Comment: Well, the trivial workaround would be to sort on the Client, with .AsEnumerable().OrderBy(...) ..Orderby is most often last statement anyway. But you might have the same behaviour in case of a GroupBy, and this appears earlier in the query.

Comment: @CaptainMorgan: I was able to reproduce this sort order using the `th-x-icu` and `th-TH-x-icu` collations on PostgreSQL 12.1 (I wrote a test that queried `pg_collation` and tested the order on all 650 collations I have). Was that `Name` column accidentally created with one of those collations?

Comment: The collation for the name column is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your database setting are having an affect on the sorting order due to the spaces between the individual character groupings. If you where to replace those spaces using the string method `Replace()` the result set might get the needed results. But, without having a PostgreSQL 12.1 Database with your specific setting it is impossible to know whether this will generate the desired results.

```
    private static void TestOrderList()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("MOUNTAIN GATE");
        list.Add("MOUNT ADA");
        list.Add("MOUNTXADA");
        list.Add("MOUNTAIN BAY APP TOAST");
        list.Add("MOUNTAIN BAY APP ATOAST");
        list.Add("MOUNTAIN BAY APPA");
        list.Add("MOUNTAIN BAY");
        list.Add("MOUNT ALFRED");
        list.Add("MOUNTAIN VIEW");
        list.Add("MOUNT BEAUTY");

        var q = list.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r.Replace("~", ""));
        q.ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
    }
```

**Disclaimer**: This is not so much a solution, but more like a test case. I choose a Tilda since it is low on the sorting order of ASCII characters.

Answer (score -3):

I have not changed any logic, but a simple iteration gave me the expected results.

```
public class LinqOrderingForWords
{
    IList<string> _places;

    public LinqOrderingForWords()
    {
        _places = new List<string> { "MOUNT ADA", "MOUNTAIN BAY", "MOUNT BEAUTY", "MOUNTAIN VIEW", "MOUNTAIN GATE", "MOUNT ALFRED", "MOUNT ADA ONE" };
    }

    public void OrderPlaces()
    {
        var sorted = _places.OrderBy(s => s);
        sorted.ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
    }
}
```

See the dotnet [fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nRx4Xd).

Is this what you desire to see?

Comment: Could you reproduce the wrong result ? That would be necessary to proof, this is a solution.

Comment: I dont get it to repro the wrong output. Its linq feature i happen to see the correct ordering. I used a model to have the names along with another prop as Uid (just for giving closest match).

Comment: A proper repro would involve execution on a PostgreSQL server.

Comment: That won't do it. OP is using PostgreSQL. I couldn't reproduce it on my 12.1 installation because I don't even have a "en_US.UTF-8" collation

Comment: does it matter? I am not getting the point. Once the data is retrieved from any source, its the .net fx linq conversion over the data, should be consistent, isnt it?

Comment: Yes, it matters. The point is that the incorrect order OP got was sorted on the server because `.OrderBy()` was translated to `ORDER BY` in the query. So in order to reproduce it, you have to use the same server and collation.